# How to convert string to just the values of the string

Tags: javascript, function

I want to convert a string such as 'String' to the stripped version of that (I think thats the word?), something like this:

```js
const strip = r => {
/* Code */
}
```

What I want is:

```js
> strip('String')
> String
```

basically I just want it to remove the quotes from around a string
(I want the output to be a none-type)

Comment: > strip('String') <== This string literal does not contain quotes.

Comment: Thats the point, it shouldn't contain quotes, the output shouldnt be a String, it should be a none-type (I think thats the right word)

Comment: It seems like your question might be bringing a little confusion. Are you trying to transform the string `'String'` into a `String` object (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/String)?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after?

```js
var test = "\"'String \" with 'quotes'\"";
test = test.replace(/['"]/g, "");
console.log("test: " + test);
```

Comment: Not really, I want them completely gone, such that if you ran the code inside the console you would get a error (normally) reading, '{Character} is not defined'
I want the code to do that

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the string passed as an argument to the `strip` function does not have quotes in its content. You're just telling that function that the `r` parameter is of type string with the content `String`.

To answer to your question, you can remove the quotes of a string by removing the first and last character:

```
const strip = str => {
  return str.slice(1, -1);
}

strip('"String"') => String
```

Comment: Thats close to what I want', but not exactly, I want the string input to only have the default quotes (strip("String")), no extra quotes I want to remove.